# Saving empty data model after pulling data from Cloud Firestore with Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, google-cloud-firestore, swift5, nsmanagedobject

The problem I am having is that Core Data is not saving correctly after communicating to Firestore database. I want to have every post's user image and name store in a cache for performance. Currently, I have two data model named `Users` and `PostItem`. `Users` is the one handling the user data that I want to save. I successfully was able to implement `PostItem`, but not `Users`.

I think it has something to deal with Firestore, but not entirely sure. The code:

```swift
     private var userName = String()
        private var imageLink = String()
        private var db = Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
        
        func fetchUser(_ id: String) -> String {
            db.document(id).getDocument { (snap, err) in
                if let snap = snap, snap.exists {
                    self.userName = snap.data()!["userName"] as! String
                } else {
                    print("Document does not exist")
                }
            }
            print("DB: \(self.userName)")
            return self.userName
        }
        
        func fetchUserImage(_ id: String) -> String {
            db.document(id).getDocument { (snap, err) in
                if let snap = snap, snap.exists {
                    self.imageLink = snap.data()!["image"] as? String ?? ""
                }else{
                    print("Document does not exist")
                }
            }
            print("DB: \(self.imageLink)")
            return self.imageLink
        }
        
        func setUpPosts(managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
            if !self.newposts.isEmpty{
                for i in self.newposts{
                    let user = Users(context: managedObjectContext)
                    print("Fetched Name: \(self.fetchUser(i.user))")
                    user.name = self.userName
                    print("Fetched Image: \(self.fetchUserImage(i.user))")
                    user.image = self.fetchUserImage(i.user)
                    user.uuid = i.user
                    
                    let post = PostItem(context: managedObjectContext)
                    post.type = i.type
                    post.user = i.user
                    post.image = i.thumb
                    post.id = i.id
                    post.text = i.text
                    post.comment = i.comments
                    post.video = i.media
                    do{
                        try managedObjectContext.save()
                    }catch{
                        print(error)
                    }
                    self.clearNewPosts()
                }
            }
        }
```

`setUpPosts()` is called from within the initializer of the class handling all post data for the views.

Comment: Using print statements result in empty Strings, which is not helpful. Starting to think that fetch*() does not return what is actually being pulled from Firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Firebase calls are asynchronous. In your code, `db.document(id).getDocument` is an asynchronous call, hence `self.userName` and `self.imageLink` will be empty/`nil` when you return from `fetchUser`/`fetchUserImage`.

Firestore uses a local cache anyway (from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline): "For Android and iOS, offline persistence is enabled by default."), so I wouldn't recommend implementing your own cache.

For caching images, I'd recommend taking a look at FirebaseUI for iOS - is provides an [integration with SDWebImage](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/tree/master/Storage), which will handle caching for you.

Comment: Dear @Peter, does the cache really persist the retrieved data locally? I understood that it helps if client and db get out of sync during the app is offline. But what if the app/iPhone has been restarted and the Firestore getDocument will be called or a snapshot listener will be added again.  I want to avoid to load ALL the documents on every app start. So I thought they way should be to store the retrieved data into Core Data and add a filter to the Firestore fetch do get only documents that are newer than the last saved document in Core Data. Thank you, Sebastian

Comment: The default cache size is 100MB, and you can adjust it using `settings.cacheSizeBytes`, like this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_cache_size

Comment: @PeterFriese - thank you for the answers! This seems to be a contentious topic since it's a bit unclear whether Firestore can be used for offline access to lower costs, or to simply give placeholder data for when a user enters a tunnel. In my example, I have a chat app, and want to avoid reloading old messages every time the user open the app. The thought is to store these in core data, and create firestore listeners to load anything newer than the newest messages in CoreData. Is this behavior possible with Firestore? Can a listener be told to ignore object IDs that already exist in cache?

Comment: Misha- one option for doing what you suggest (use Cora Data to cache) that might be suitable for a chat app isto filter for any messages that are newer than a specific date. That being said, I would encourage you to (a) use the pricing calculator to see if Firestore is actually going to cost you as much as you think it is, and (b) consider using RTDB (which charges per GB transferred as opposed to document reads/writes).